# How to find and replace variable assignment at the end of a line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, delay, expansion

Using windows batch scripting, I'm trying to search and replace a variable assignment within a file.

It gets weird since the assigned value is always changing and because the variable is at the end of the line. Here is what the file contains:

```
*##========================================================
*## This file was generated on 09-18-2007 at 10:21:56
*##========================================================
DEBUG-LEVEL = 10     APP-DELIVERY = 35

PROGRAM-CONTROL...
  DUPLICATE-CONDITION-CHECK  = N
  GENERATE-SETUP             = N
  GENERATE-ENV               = Y
```

I am trying to replace the assigned value of the APP-DELIVERY variable, so I would like to write a script that would change the 35 to a 36 for example.

I've found many answers on how I would go about replacing static strings with another string, but I haven't found anything yet regarding changing the value of a variable, much less one that is at the end of a line. Also with the answers I've found, I have been unsure of how to deal with the equals sign.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do, however...  I would suggest you look into a Windows version of the `sed` utility.

Comment: my apologies for the lack of clarity. What you are seeing there is the contents of a file, which has a variable I'd like to change the value of (APP-DELIVERY). Currently it is set to the value of 35, but I am trying to set it to a different value using a batch script.

Comment: You have to read all file content, make the necessary changes and write the result to an output file. Changes depend a lot of the file content. So do you just want to know how to change some text at the end of the line?

Comment: @RYC: `sed` was designed to solve this problem.  Find it here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "^" q20958786.txt') DO (
 SET line=%%b
 CALL :subs %1
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
:subs
:: Empty line?
IF NOT DEFINED line echo(&GOTO :EOF
:: What's after APP-DELIVERY[space]?
SET lineend=%line:*APP-DELIVERY =%
:: No APP-DELIVERY[sp]?
IF "%lineend%"=="%line%" echo(%line%&GOTO :EOF
:: Does the end part start "= " ?
IF NOT "%lineend:~0,2%"=="= " echo(%line%&GOTO :EOF
:: If so, see whether it terminates with a decimal number
SET lineend=%lineend:~2%
SET "value="
SET /a value=%lineend% >NUL 2>NUL
:: Value will now have that decimal or be empty
IF NOT "%value%"=="%lineend%"  echo(%line%&GOTO :EOF
:: Valid decimal - lop off the end of the line, character-by-character
:loploop
SET line=%line:~0,-1%
SET lineend=%lineend:~1%
IF DEFINED lineend GOTO loploop
:: Plug  our replacement supplied as %1 to the batch.
ECHO(%line%%1
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a batch that should do as you require. It reads your input file (I've nominated that as `q20958786.txt` - what you call it is up to you) and produces an output file `newfile.txt`.

The comments should show you waht's happening.

Run it as `thisbatch replacementvalue`

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully, the failsafes are also a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

This should change the 35 to whatever you like.  It's 36 in the code below.

It uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.log" | repl "(^DEBUG-LEVEL = .*APP-DELIVERY =).*" "$1 36" >"newfile.log"
```

Comment: This also works, but isn't very portable. Thanks though!